# Content generator for development site

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, content

Does anybody knows good plugin which can generate dummy posts/tags/categories/users and write dummy comments? I want to generate some content on my development (localhost) site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always use the [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) that Theme Reviewers use to evaluate themes for the Repo. It's got pretty much everything you need to style/worry about.

And if I need to create batch content in a different way, then I use [WP Dummy Content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dummy-content/)